# How to add sort by date at Magento Backend

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I want to show all my products by default from newest to oldest. I saw this links:

[First solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237513/magento-sort-by-date-added)

[Second solution](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/280314/#t387709)

And also [this](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-category-page-product-sorting) one. All of them show same solution, but always for Frontend.

What I want is to set by default on **System->Configuration->Catalog->Product Listing sort by** and set it by default to **Created at**, and I want also to set the order (desc or asc).

Any ideas on how to customize that?

Comment: The product's ID will tell you in what order they were created :)

Comment: btw, this is correct. if you only want to sort the grid and not see the creation date, ordering by id is enough.

Comment: Hummm but... how can I order by id while on backend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry I didn't answer your question.

The grid is ordered by entity_id:

```
// app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php:41
$this->setDefaultSort('entity_id');
$this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
```

This means, your wanted behaviour should be default.

Comment: Actually it's not working. It still remains the same. But I've learned a lot with your code.

Comment: what is your behaviour? delete your cookies, log into the backend, what is the key the grid is sort by?

Answer (score 2):

You can install [GridControl](https://github.com/magento-hackathon/GridControl) and write an extension and add this to an grid.xml which you created in the module

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gridcontrol>
    <grids>
        <product.grid>
            <add>
                <header>Created at</header>
                <type>int</type>
                <index>created_at</index>
          </add>        
        </product.grid>
    </grids>
</gridcontrol>
```

This solution is not tested.

Comment: GridControl is an extension to easily add new columns to grids. With the above code, you can add the created_at column. I just saw, that you can not order by this column with the extenion. so you have two ways: extend the extension to change the default order or write your own extension to change it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to go about it without changing any core files is to copy the Toolbar.php file located:

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php
```

then create a new directory path (if you haven't created one) under:

```
/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php
```

Now replace the following from line 232:

```
    if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
        $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
    }
```

to

```
if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
if(($this->getCurrentOrder())=='position'){ //defines the sort option
//sort by position (ascending) and entity_id (descending)
$this->_collection->addAttributeToSort('position','asc')->addAttributeToSort('entity_id','desc');
} else {
$this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(),$this->getCurrentDirection());
}
}
```

Lastly, reindex and refresh cache on your Magento backend and your ready to go.