# Best Practice editing sort options in Magento 1.9

Tags: sorting, magento, magento-1.9

I have a question for the community. I am working with a Magento 1.9 ecommerce app and the client would like to customize the sort filter and add a field that doesn't currently exist. When I search for ways to do this, the only options I'm finding suggest editing the core code files. This seems like bad practice as it would then be impossible to update.

Does anyone know of a better way to customize the sort filters? To add, for example, the ability to sort by date the product was created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the core files for customizing the filters. Please refer to this link for further details.

[Magento - Sort by Date Added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237513/magento-sort-by-date-added)